# Visualizing plots stored in a list

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, tibble

I am new to R and I have a tibble with 3 columns, the last of which is a list storing multiple plots. I would like to write a function to visualize each of those plots but up to now I do not know how. The tibble looks like this:

[image]

It was made with ggplot and grouped by species and type.
I am able to see each plot with `data$plots[1]` and so forth, but I would like to write a function so I don't have to do it for every single plot.
Could anyone help, please?

Comment: with the patchwork package, you can probably do `patchwork::wrap_plots(your_tibble$plots)`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a function to solve this problem

```
plot_extract<- function(directory) {

for(i in 1:9){
    print(data$plots[i])
 }
}
```

The **wrap_plots** function from the **patchwork** package also worked.
Thanks!